# How to fire ajax requests from multiple Vue components mount() in succession

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

Basically I have a list of items. When I click on an item, it causes a Vue component to mount and fire an axios call to my node server to get some data.

```
async mount () {
  try {
    let ajaxCall = await fetchData()
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}



fetchData () {
  return axios.get('/dataEndpoint', {})
}
```

Ordinarily, clicking an item and receiving data work fine, **except**, when I click another item before the first has a chance to finish. I.e. I'm clicking multiple items in rapid succession, causing multiple mounts and thus, multiple ajax calls.

I'm aware of `Promise.all`, and being able to fire off a set of `axios` calls, but isn't that really when all the calls go out at once?

Am I missing something fundamental about the way browsers/node.js handle multiple concurrent ajax requests? Or is it that `mount()` in Vue that has some nuances around making something like this happen?

Comment: Even if the requests are fired in succession, they don't respond in succession. I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @JacobGoh My guess is that the problem doesn’t actually lie with Vue, but with my Node API endpoint, which upon receiving a request from the client, fires an axios call to a third party API. Fetching one at a time works, but if my endpoint receives multiple successive hits, it just fails.

Comment: may i know what's the error message you are getting ?

Comment: @JacobGoh error `undefined` unfortunately. I’ll have to dig into it, but can Node fundamentally deal with these concurrent connections? Or would I need to queue all incoming and then outgoing requests?

Comment: Yes, node can deal with that for sure. My first guess would be that the third party API is rate limited and the error wasn't handled properly in the API endpoint.

Comment: @JacobGoh ok, I’ll give it a better whirl tomorrow and update here. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mount()` is working as it should be. `Vue` or any other framework shouldn't consider the fact how many ajax calls you're making in the process. It's upto you how you want to design the user experience. From your scenario I can see the following solutions:

- Take all of the list items ajax call into a single API and load them in your viewModel when the list itself is mounted - rather than loading them individually
- Make other items disabled of clicking unless the previous API call is completed
- Create a small plugin that'll maintain a queue for maintaining these API calls, put a small loader to make the users feel that its in process and that plugin will let component know the returning result